# Android in app purchase, show price

Tags: android

I have implemented in my Android app an in-app purchase, and I would show the localized price in my panel. I have searched many solution but there doesn't work. What is the correct way to show the in-app purchase price in my panel (activity), if the IAP code is i.e. id.myapp.purchase?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query items you have added to developer console
look at this google document

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails